# clip values with specific conditions in pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a dataframe which looks like -

```
data = {'col_0': ['a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'b','b','b'], 'col_1': [-2, -7, 6, 8, -5, 2, 6]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df

col_0   col_1
a       -2
a       -7
a        6
a        8
b       -5
b        2
b        6
```

What I want is to clip the values of col_1 between -2 to 2 if col_0 is a.

Things that I have tried till now are -

```
df.loc[df['col_0']=='a',"col_1"].clip(lower = -2, upper = 2,inplace=True) 

df.loc[df['col_0']=='a',"col_1"] = df.loc[df['col_0']=='a',"col_1"].clip(lower = -2, upper = 2)
```

Comment: What's wrong with your 2nd approach?

Comment: It seems your second approach is correct.

Comment: Yes, I just realised That my second approach is correct. I must have made some mistake in the notebook

Answer (score 1, accepted):

df.loc[df['col_0']=='a',"col_1"] = df.loc[df['col_0']=='a',"col_1"].clip(lower = -2, upper = 2)